# Calculate difference of two dates in SQL

Tags: sql, date, compare

I have a table that contains 2 date/time columns (CreatedDateTime / LastModifiedDateTime):

```
Item   CreatedDateTime            LastModifiedDateTime

1      2016-03-18 18:49:36.557    2016-03-22 18:51:10.950

2      2016-03-22 17:32:57.610    2016-03-22 17:37:26.790
```

I would like to:

1. Calculate the difference between **CreatedDateTime** and today's date (to give me an 'age')
2. Calculate the difference between **LastModifiedDateTime** and today's date (to give me an idea of iactivity)

With 2. above, I want to be able to report on an *Item* that has not been 'modified' (LastModifiedDateTime) in a while.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? There are differences between different dialects, so the one you are using is highly relevant. Please [edit] to include the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL SERVER:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(Item                 INT
              , CreatedDateTime      DATETIME
              , LastModifiedDateTime DATETIME);

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES
      (1
     , '2016-03-18 18:49:36.557'
     , '2016-03-22 18:51:10.950'),
      (2
     , '2016-03-22 17:32:57.610'
     , '2016-03-22 17:37:26.790');
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT A.Item
    , A.CreatedDateTime
    , A.LastModifiedDateTime
    , Age = DATEDIFF(day,A.CreatedDateTime,GETDATE())
    , inactivity = DATEDIFF(day,A.LastModifiedDateTime,GETDATE())
FROM   #Temp AS A;
```

RESULT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATEDIFF() function for the age and GETDATE() function for the current date.

You will just need to enter DATEDIFF(day,CreatedDateTime,GETDATE()), or a similar query.

Datediff() will also allow you to take month, hour, or other time measures.

Also with #2, you could throw in some CASE WHEN LastModifiedDateTime IS NULL THEN ... to give yourself a different report on that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `DATEDIFF()` function returns the time between two dates.

**Syntax** DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate);

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

Result

> ### DiffDate
>
> 61

Swapping the dates would result in a negative result.

Comment: That's useful and easy for me to understand - thanks!